# Can HTTP and HTTPS share same port on the (same) proxy server?

Tags: proxy, port

While setting proxies in Ubuntu at my work place, I realized that the following does not work as expected:

```
http_proxy=http://myproxy:8080   # this works
https_proxy=https://myproxy:8080 # this does not
```

The fix was:
https_proxy=http://myproxy:8080

My suspicion is that my connection up to the proxy server is insecure and we are being fooled. If that is actually the case, how could I demonstrate the same? The PORTs being same for both HTTP and HTTPS makes me feel mighty confident about the problem, and I would like to know if I could be wrong.

TIA

PS: Edited the title

Comment: In my experience it means that both http and https traffic should go through the proxy, and the proxy only then establishes TLS connection to the target server. At least this is how it works in Burp Suite (pentest proxy tool). So I guess it depends on what is your proxy and what is its functionality - you can always set up an exclusively https-proxy, if you configure TLS cert for it and all that. Do you have access to the proxy config or the proxy machine? You could take a look at what traffic goes there.